# How to simplify the code by using a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I should find a method to determine if a word appears in a 2D array diagonally (from top left to bottom right).
My method: *static boolean findText (...)* works in this case because LEGO has 4 letters but of course that's not how you want it to look like and it should be also be able to work for longer and shorter words.
How can I do a loop that repeats the `if (texts[k][i] == searchText[k])`  as often as the searchText is long (so basically searchText.length)? Without messing up the other loop that works perfectly fine at the moment.

```java
class FindText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] textField = {
                {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'L', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'x'},
                {'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'E', 'm', 'n', 'a', 'b'},
                {'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'G', 'u'},
                {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'O', 'y'},
                {},
                null};
        char[] searchText = {'L', 'E', 'G', 'O'};
        Out.print("\nText-Feld:\n--------------------------------\n");
        print(textField);
        Out.print("\n--------------------------------\n");
        print(searchText);
        if (findText(textField, searchText)) {
            Out.print("\nkommt vor!");
        } else {
            Out.print("\nkommt nicht vor!");
        }
    } // end main

    static boolean findText(char[][] texts, char[] searchText) {
        if (texts == null) return false;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            if (texts[k][i] == searchText[k]) {
                if (texts[k + 1][i + 1] == searchText[k + 1]) {
                    if (texts[k + 2][i + 2] == searchText[k + 2]) {
                        if (texts[k + 3][i + 3] == searchText[k + 3]) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    } // end findText()

    static void print(char[][] texts) {
        if (texts == null) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            if (texts[i] != null) print(texts[i]);
            Out.print("\n");
        }
    } // end printTexts()

    static void print(char[] text) {
        if (text == null) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            Out.print(text[i]);
        }
    } // end printText()
} // end class FindText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't have {null} as a possible entry in your multi-dimensional array then, this would be a simple solution

However, because I guess null is a possible entry then, you would need a way to check the value of each entry before iterating over it. For instance, `texts[i].length` would crash when it reaches the null value.

EDIT: Because {null} are possible entries, I have just added simple if statement before entering the 2nd loop. This should work for searching diagonally left top down, I believe.

EDIT: Had to add another small null check in the 1st if of the 3rd loop.

```java
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    if (texts[i] != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < texts[i].length; j++) {
            // If the 1st letter matches
            if (texts[i][j] == searchText[0]) {
                // then iterate over the size of the "searchtext"
                for (int k = 1; k < searchText.length; k++) {
                    // If the position of the next letter exists & is equal to
                    // what is in the search word, then increment some variable
                    if ((i + k < texts.length &&
                            texts[i + k] != null &&
                            j + k < texts[i + k].length) &&
                            texts[i + k][j + k] == searchText[k]) {
                        size += 1;
                    }
                    // If we are on the last letter
                    if (k == searchText.length - 1) {
                        // return true if we have found the search word
                        if (size == searchText.length - 1) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            // Otherwise reset the size and
                            // keep iterating over the texts[][]
                            size = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thx, it works. I would have not thought that it would afford so much coding for that.